# The number of “Requests” is very large

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

I tested my website performance with Gtmetrix. I found that my website performance seems to be good, but the number of “Requests” is very large. I want to know if the impact of this problem is big? If there is a big impact on website performance, how can I solve this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your site performance is good. But if you want to reduce request of site, magento 2 provide default Merge CSS and Merge JS feature. You can make it enable from admin.

```
Select Store >> Configuration >> Advanced >> Developer >> JavaScript Settings >> Merge JavaScript Files

Select Store >> Configuration >> Advanced >> Developer >> CSS Settings >> Merge CSS Files
```

Also, to reduce request you can configure CDN. And from CDN you can download images, JS and CSS filrs from CDN.

So, above changes will reduce your request and will improve your site performance.

Comment: `Stores => Settings => Configuration => Advanced => Developer => JavaScript Settings => Merge JavaScript Files` and
`Stores => Settings => Configuration => Advanced => Developer => CSS Settings => Merge CSS Files`